# How to pass a data-attribute from elixir phoenix to an input field so that the label does not get changed to lowercase

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to pass attributes to an input field which contain capital letters like `data-clearLabel="clear"`. Because I'm using the bulma [calendar](https://creativebulma.net/product/calendar) extension.

I tried something like this:

```
<%= date_input f, :from, "data-clearLabel": gettext("clear"), "data-todayLabel": gettext("today") %>
```

But it turns into this html:

```
<input data-clearlabel="leeren" data-todaylabel="heute" id="csv_from" name="csv[from]" type="text" class="is-hidden">
```

As you can see `data-todayLabel` turns into `data-todaylabel`. How do I change that behavio(u)r?

I also tried to use `... data: [todayLabel: gettext("today"), ...]` without any luck.

Comment: Would not `data-today_label` do the trick?

Comment: YES! @AlekseiMatiushkin: Please provide an answer saying `"data-today_label": gettext("today")` does the trick so that I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common convention between backend and frontend would be:

- backend uses underscored variable names, that are mapped to
- camel-cased variable names on the frontend.

That said, the following would do the trick:

```js
... "data-today_label": gettext("today") ...
```